# using PPP without TCP/IP

Tags: ppp, pppd, tcp-ip

I'm using a PPP to communicate with a device. So far what I have been doing is instantiating PPP on my machine (Fedora 29) and on the device (Yocto Linux). Then I open a TCP/UDP socket and communicate with the device. My serial link (which is why I use PPP) has low baud rate, 4800 to be exact. I cannot change it, it is a project requirement. I've been doing some reading about PPP and as far as I understand I can't just instantiate it and use it raw. I'm have to use TCP/IP/UDP. Am I correct? In other words once I have a PPP connection the only way to use is to open a socket (UDP or TCP) and talk to the device through it. I can't just create my application level packet and tell PPP to send it, I have to go through TCP/IP layer (transport layer).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PPP can run protocols other than IP; the most common is of course IPv6. But numerous others have been (and maybe still are) run over PPP. Wikipedia even has a [list of protocols that run over PPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-Point_Protocol#Multiple_network_layer_protocols), though I'm not sure how many work on Linux.

Also — the reason you run PPP over a serial link is because you *want* to run a higher-level protocol like IP. If you want to avoid that overhead, just use the serial link directly. Serial links don't require PPP; you can send raw binary data over RS232 using whatever application-specific protocol you'd like.